# Entity Framework Code First Azure connection

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, connection-string, code-first

I am using Entity Framework Code First 4.3 + Azure and having difficulties connecting to the database. The error I get is the following (on the first query):

```
Keyword not supported: 'server'.
```

I have the following connection set up in my Web.config

```
<configSections>
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDBContext"
         connectionString="Server=tcp:[SUBSCR].database.windows.net,1433;Database=[MyDB];User ID=[user];Password=[pass];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;PersistSecurityInfo=True"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My DbContext implementing class uses the connection string's name:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
    {
        public MyContext()
            : base("TestDBContext")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        }
```

Can you tell what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem.

You're missing all the metadata in the connection string that Entity Framework requires. The connection string provided by SQL Azure needs to inserted within the `provider connection string` parameter of EF's connection string.

`<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;[PUT SQL AZURE CONN STRING HERE]&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

You'll need to use the metadata from your own project. I pulled that metadata from an EF project generating from an existing database.

Comment: I'm using EF code first + DbContext (I'm not generating my data model from the database) so I don't have any metadata available at development time.

Comment: @Sese If you're using Code First, then your connection string provider should be `System.Data.SqlClient` not `System.Data.EntityClient`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved, putting in the web.config this connectionstring:

```
<add name="eManagerTurModelConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ORM.eManagerFinanceModel.csdl|res://*/ORM.eManagerFinanceModel.ssdl|res://*/ORM.eManagerFinanceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=<server>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=eManagerTur;Integrated Security=False;User ID=<user>;Password=<Password>;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And after I removed the connectionstring of my website, worked, because it was not getting the connection string that I added in my web.config.

English bad... =)

Answer (score 2):

The provider should be providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

I connected to Azure from VS and then looked at the properties and set my connection string and provider name.

```
 <add name="context" connectionString="Data Source=myServer,myPort;Initial Catalog=myDBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUserName;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I was then able to run update-database with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

i tried like this, it may help you. may be 1433 is making problem, is it port no ? or what? . try like this.

check this link [Windows Azure with Sql](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/)

```
<add name="dbContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: tried it, it doesn't work...1433 is the default port for sql server and I copy pasted the connection string from my Azure subscription/database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Data Source=tcp:YOUR-DATABASE-HERE.database.windows.net,1433;
>   Database=GolfRounds; 
>               User ID=YOUR-USERNAME@YOUR-SERVER; Password=YOUR-PASSWORD; Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True;

There is also an MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951633.aspx that may be helpful.

Comment: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where I did not have access to the metadata, in this case you need to use System.Data.SqlClient as the provider. You will also need to add MultipleActiveResultSets=True to your connection string